# Can anybody provide XMLTextReader Custom Logic to read large XML fast...?

Tags: c#, xml

I want a help that i need a custom logic to read large XML of size 1GB.

Thanks 
sivaram

Comment: The XmlReader implementations in .NET, especially the one of XmlTextReader are very fast. It is questionable whether its speed can be improved substantially.

You may have problems finding memory to store the parsed data, but your question is just about speed...

Answer (score 1):

the following code snippet might help you:

```
private void readXML() {
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    //configure xml reader settings...
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml", settings)){
        while (reader.Read()){
            //read xml content..
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```